# What is wrong with this Microsoft Bot Framework Token Request?

Tags: oauth, botframework

## Update 5/30/2017

I was able to get the token using cURL, but still no luck with Postman.  Here's the curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=<your_id>&client_secret=<your_secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

## Original Question

As per the instructions on Microsoft's official docs for developing a bot with REST, I am sending a request in Postman to get an oauth token to use to work with their bot REST API.

Here's my setup in Postman (which is using Interceptor so I can specify Host):

**Headers**
[image: Headers]

**Body**
[image: Body]

And, here's the response:

```
{
"error": "invalid_scope",
"error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' 
is not valid. The scope https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default is not valid.
\r\nTrace ID: 8b09d0ba-3ec0-4f15-9280-7527d46c1600\r\nCorrelation ID: 43b0fa8f-5b73-444c-
a1e4-9f3dd82c0d86\r\nTimestamp: 2017-05-30 22:17:05Z",
"error_codes": [70011],
"timestamp": "2017-05-30 22:17:05Z",
"trace_id": "8b09d0ba-3ec0-4f15-9280-7527d46c1600",
"correlation_id": "43b0fa8f-5b73-444c-a1e4-9f3dd82c0d86"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? I followed the instructions and I'm sure the client ID and secret ID are correct.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks @ezequiel for cleaning this up

Comment: What are you trying to do ? For what do you need that token. BTW: I just want to know. :D

Comment: @BobSwager Hahah, sure! I am developing a bot using REST (as opposed to Node or .NET). So, my server handles all the bot logic - what to say, when to say it, etc etc. It is the 'Bot Connector' in the MS Bot Framework that acts as the middle man between the user (using Skype, Slack, etc.) and my server. For the Bot Connector to accept my messages, I need this token first.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication for deetz and a visual explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that Postman and cURL are not treating the parameters on the same way. I tested with your parameters and got the same result, but I then got it working with Postman simply by avoiding the encoding of the URL in `scope` value: `https://api.botframework.com/.default` instead of `https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default`.

See capture below:
[image: working version]

And no need to specify the Host in the Header section.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!